# Extract data between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables. one table is request types and another is request rights. based on employee rights i need to show all the request type with employee assigned request type to true. i want to get reqtype for a particular employee.

for eg:-

```
   Request type table 
  ------------------------

   REQID  REqName   ISACTIVE
---------------------------------  
    1      a           true
    2      b           true
    3      c           true

 REquest Rights table
-------------------------

   ID  ReTYpeId  EmpId  ISActive
 ----------------------------------
   1     1        21      true
   2     2        21      true
   3     1        22      true

  RESult Table 
-----------------------
  REQID   REqName  ISACTIVE
---------------------------------
    1      a           true
    2      b           true
    3      c           false
```

How to query this one.

so far i tried this much

```
 SELECT tt.TransactionTypeName,tt.TransactionTypeId,tt.IsActive  FROM sTransactionType tt JOIN sTransactionRights tr
 ON tr.TransTypeID=tt.TransactionTypeId
 WHERE tt.Division=1  AND tt.IsActive=1. i tried with case in isactive .but not working at all.
```

Comment: what u have tried for 'this one'? Please show some efforts towards solving problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT REQID, REqName, ISNULL(r.ISActive, 'false') AS ISACTIVE
FROM [Request type table] t
LEFT JOIN [REquest Rights table] r ON r.ReTYpeId = t.REQID AND EmpId  = 21
WHERE t.ISACTIVE = 'true'
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. its giving only employee assigned request types.

Comment: i think it must be modified at certain extent! @JarekBielicki you are missing the ',' in separating the filed names and also table alias! Edited your answer!